# Using import.io on a php page

Tags: import.io

HI trying to run an import io api on a php page and no data is detected. 
Is it possible to obtain data from  [here](http://www.charityperformance.com/charity-search.php)

or similar web pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create an API to a PHP page. I have created an API for this website, without any issue.

https://import.io/data/mine/?id=628e1406-9674-4196-b2e2-43a5f49262f4

You can also paginate nicely with this website, as the URL pattern is consistent and you do not need cookies.

http://www.charityperformance.com/charity-search.php?start=20&cat=&search=
http://www.charityperformance.com/charity-search.php?start=40&cat=&search=

If you would like to chat about a specific issue or website, I would suggest contacting support@import.io for further help.

Thanks,
Meg

Comment: HI thanks for your reply - I don't know why import.io could not load that page yesterday, know it works fine for me too..